# Table new line when to much columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

We have a table were the columns are populated by data, which is different for each table and we don't know how much columns we will have.

When there are to much columns the table gets to long. So when the amount of columns is more than 4, the table should start a new line. The title of each row should be copied as well.

This image should make it clear:

[image: Example table]

**Note**: The table does not have a fixed width, the width is depended of which device you use so should have a width of 100% and not a fixed pixel width.

All the columns have the same height and width but are not fixed values, these are also depended of the width of the device used.

When the red block is going to a new line, all the rows should stay stacked on top of each other. The 3 rows should be seen as 1 row so to speak.

Comment: Have you considered just make a link column and move most of the detail columns to another page which link column goes to?

Comment: If I understand you correctly this isn't an option. The information is actually like this: Row 1: Title of item, Row 2: Weight of item, Row 3: Barcode of item. So every column is a new item and the rows are the information of the item. So for me it's not possible to remove some columns because that would remove items and their information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still have some bug **Carefully**

You need to use JS/jQuery to create new header when overflow

like this!

```js
//Put to document ready
checktable();
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  checktable();
});


function checktable() {
  if ($(window).width() < $(document).width()) {
    if ($('tr.extended').length < 1) {
      $('tr').not('.extended').each(function(i, e) {
        $(document.createElement('tr'))
          .addClass('extended')
          .append($(e).html())
          .appendTo('#table');
        $(e).children('td').each(function(j, ele) {
          var eot = +$(ele).offset().left +
            +$(ele).width();
          if ($(window).width() < eot) {
            $(ele).hide();
            $('tr.extended').eq(i)
              .children('td').eq(j)
              .show();
          } else {
            $(ele).show();
            $('tr.extended').eq(i)
              .children('td').eq(j)
              .hide();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  } else {
    $('td').not('.extended').show();
    $('.extended').remove();
  }
}
```

```css
td,
th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>
      head
    </th>
    <td>
      so long data 1
    </td>
    <td>
      so long data 2
    </td>
    <td>
      so long data 3
    </td>
    <td>
      so long data 4
    </td>
    <td>
      so long data 5
    </td>
    <td>
      so long data 6
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      head2
    </th>
    <td>
      much long data 1
    </td>
    <td>
      much long data 2
    </td>
    <td>
      much long data 3
    </td>
    <td>
      much long data 4
    </td>
    <td>
      much long data 5
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to achieve the desired behaviour, `display: inline-block;` on the table cells should be the most basic one.

I also recommend [this CSS Tricks post about responsive tables](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/) to improve the usability of your tables on small screens.

```css
table {
  max-width: 100%; /* obviously */
}

td {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
    <td>ccccccccccccccccccccccccc</td>
    <td>ddddddddddddddddddddddddd</td>
    <td>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not totally what I need because it's not just 1 row that needs to be put on the next line, it's 3 rows that need to be stacked on each other and stay together on the new line, will edit my question for clarification.